# Jackson Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson

i am having problem with deserializing JSON string. I think i tried everything and i got stuck. This is my code so far. Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Entity:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ImportTask {
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private long id;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String description;

    public ImportTask() {
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Client:

```
List<ImportTask> importTaskList = new ArrayList<ImportTask>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jacksonJaxbJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
jacksonJaxbJsonProvider.setMapper(mapper);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig(jacksonJaxbJsonProvider));
Response response= client
                     .target("http://localhost:51873/api/getImportTaskList")
                     .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .get();
importTaskList = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<ImportTask>>(){});
```

This is JSON string i get from webservice:

```
"[{\"ID\":16,\"Name\":\"name\",\"Description\":\"description\"}]"
```

i am getting this error

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream.
.......
```

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can
>   not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING
>   token

Is error related to Id being passed as int not string?
Any help would be much apprecieted.

Comment: Might be related to reading the entity from the response, rather than your model itself. For instance if you read the value from `String` from your `ObjectMapper`, by parametrizing with `new TypeReference<List<ImportTask>>(){}`, it will successfully de-serialize.

Comment: Your JSON is a JSON String, not a JSON array, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sotirios is correct.

Problem is with webservice returning strings instead of json.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a string not jsonString.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.readValue("returning",String.class);
// then,your operation...
```